# How to add Unique values in a Data Frame in R

Tags: r

I have a Data frame with 100000 observations and there is one column called Student_Id with 78271 unique values.
I want to add a new column in the data frame which contains all the unique values i.e. 78721 and remaining 21279 observation with NA.

INPUT:

```
x3 <- data.frame(
      x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6),
      x2 = c(T, F, T, F, T, T, T, F, F, F, T, T, T, F, T)
)
View(x3)
```

| x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 2 | FALSE |
| 2 | TRUE |
| 3 | FALSE |
| 3 | TRUE |
| 4 | TRUE |
| 4 | TRUE |
| 5 | FALSE |
| 5 | FALSE |
| 6 | TRUE |
| 6 | FALSE |
| 7 | FALSE |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 8 | TRUE |
| 2 | FALSE |
| 9 | TRUE |
| 3 | FALSE |
| 10 | FALSE |
| 4 | TRUE |
| 11 | FALSE |
| 5 | TRUE |
| 12 | TRUE |
| 6 | TRUE |
| 13 | TRUE |
| 4 | TRUE |
| 14 | FALSE |
| 5 | FALSE |
| 15 | FALSE |
| 6 | FALSE |

But I want my output to be in the form

| x1 | x2 | Unique |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | 1 |
| 2 | FALSE | 2 |
| 2 | TRUE | 3 |
| 3 | FALSE | 4 |
| 3 | TRUE | 5 |
| 4 | TRUE | 6 |
| 4 | TRUE | NA |
| 5 | FALSE | NA |
| 5 | FALSE | NA |
| 6 | TRUE | NA |
| 6 | FALSE | NA |
| 7 | FALSE | NA |
| 1 | TRUE | NA |
| 8 | TRUE | NA |
| 2 | FALSE | NA |
| 9 | TRUE | NA |
| 3 | FALSE | NA |
| 10 | FALSE | NA |
| 4 | TRUE | NA |
| 11 | FALSE | NA |
| 5 | TRUE | NA |
| 12 | TRUE | NA |
| 6 | TRUE | NA |
| 13 | TRUE | NA |
| 4 | TRUE | NA |
| 14 | FALSE | NA |
| 5 | FALSE | NA |
| 15 | FALSE | NA |
| 6 | FALSE | NA |

Comment: Where is the Student_id column? I can't understand where this Unique column is supposed to come from

Comment: @V.Lou My impression is, the Unique column holds the unique values from x1, but they are just `cbind`ed to the dataframe without any relation to the position of these values in x1, which seems weird. Usually you want observations to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: group by your ID variable, and within each group look for the first row.

You won't get your example output, but from your description it seems to be what you want. In your example, you have indeed the unique values, but they aren't aligned with the original data, and it's probably not what you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
x3 %>%
  group_by(x1) %>%
  mutate(u = ifelse(row_number() == 1, x1, NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
      x1 x2        u
   <dbl> <lgl> <dbl>
 1     1 TRUE      1
 2     2 FALSE     2
 3     3 TRUE      3
 4     4 FALSE     4
 5     5 TRUE      5
 6     6 TRUE      6
 7     1 TRUE     NA
 8     2 FALSE    NA
 9     3 FALSE    NA
10     4 FALSE    NA
11     5 TRUE     NA
12     6 TRUE     NA
13     4 TRUE     NA
14     5 FALSE    NA
15     6 TRUE     NA
```